# pass correct parameters to managed dll method in c#

Tags: c#, dll, parameters

There is a external dll method :

```
public unsafe static void BV([In] int* key, [In] int* m, [In] int* n, [In] double* a, [In] double* b, [In] double* bl, [In] double* bu, [Out] double* x, [Out] double* w, [In] double* act, [In] double* zz, [Out] double* istate, [Out] int* loopa)
```

How can I pass parameters in c# as is asking for *int and *double and how to deal with in,out?

In sample code I am not able to pass parameters as method needs them. What is it wrong?

```
        int key = 0, n = 2, m = 3;
        double[] a = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
        double[] b = { 10.0, 20.0, 30.0 };
        double[] bl = { 0.0, 1.0 };
        double[] bu = { 1.0, 2.0 };
        double[] x = new double[n];
        double[] w = new double[n];
        double[] act = new double[m * (Math.Min(m, n) + 2)];
        double[] zz = new double[m];
        double[] istate = new double[n + 1];
        int loopA = 0;
        bvlsFortran.BV(key,m,n,a,b,bl,bu, x,w,act,zz,istate,loopA ); //bvlsFortran is dll file
        Console.WriteLine(loopA);
```

[image]

I was trying with

```
bvlsFortran.BV(key,m,n,a,b,bl,bu, out x,out w,act,zz,out istate, out loopA );
```

and also

```
bvlsFortran.BV(ref key,ref m,ref n,ref a,ref b,bl,bu, out x,out w,act,zz,out istate, out loopA );
```

but they do not seem to work
What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me(at least it compiles):

```
   int key = 100;
   int* keyPointer = (int*)&key;
   bvlsFortran.BV(keyPointer);
```

I am not passing other parameters, you can do it by yourself

To pass double[] you should use `fixed` keyword:

```
   double[] a = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
   fixed (double* pt = a)
   {
       bvlsFortran.BV(pt);
   }
```

`[In]`, `[Out]` attributes: it's something different from `ref` and `out`. If you want to, you can read more about [OutAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [InAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.inattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on msdn.

And one more option you can try, is to write C++/CLI wrapper for you unmanaged dll, and use it from c#, without need of using pointers and other unsafe code.

Comment: Is it possible to use it in safe context, maybe using Marshal ?

Comment: @cMinor the only way avoid using unsafe code in c# I know, to use c++/CLI wrapper

Comment: How do you apply this technique to double* to double[] ?  as double* aP = (double*)&a ...; would not work

Comment: @cMinor Updated my answer, added sample with array

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using the IntPtr structure to pass integer and double pointers to the DLL method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Also have a look at this table. It is specific to the case when calling COM/DCOM components from C# but it will give you an idea too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sak564ww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx